# An efficient Sqlite approach to this concept?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm fairly new to sqlite and from my understanding you can't store individual tables per row of a current table. Due to that, would it than be acceptable to have a table that has greater than 50+ columns or would it be best to split the columns into more tables?

To get where I'm coming here's a simplified concept of what I'm trying to create:

1. A table called History stores the data, user weight, and a foreign id referencing the exercise table.
2. In the exercise table there are columns 
   Workout-1-Name, Workout-1-Weight, Workout_1_MAX_SET,Workout_1_SET_1.,.,..,..Workout_1_SET_8

and this repeats for Workout_2 - Workout_5. As you can see it will be pretty long(Around 50 columns).

I was thinking of just creating separate tables for Workouts 1-5 but since they're all workouts wouldn't it make sense to just store them all in one table?

Also, is there a cleaner way to do this? Writing all of this out in java seems messy even with static names.

Thanks, appreciate any responses.

Comment: Have a `workouts` table with `_ID`, `num` (your 1-5 value), `name`, etc. Have a `sets` table with `_ID`, `workoutId`, `name`, etc. Have an exercises table with `_ID`, `setId`, and whatever else you need.

Comment: Having numbers on your columns seems wrong. Maybe you should consider a Workout table with 5 rows. Then a Set table with a column that references which Workout it is associated with

Comment: Thanks guys makes sense.